# RethinkDB for i586

Tags: cross-compiling, intel, rethinkdb, intel-galileo

I was wondering if there is a package for RethinkDB for the i586 architecture, or does anyone know how to cross compile it for i586?

I have an Intel Galileo Gen 2 board and trying to compile RethinkDB on it, but it takes forever, so I thought I could do it on my main computer.

My host computer is running Xubuntu 15.04, with an i7.

The Intel Galileo is running Yocto, and is i586.

So my hope is to build RethinkDB on my host machine for the Intel Galileo. If I can't cross compile it, does anyone know how to emulate i586 on my main computer?

Comment: You may want to mention which OS's the respective systems are running.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Edited the question

Comment: There are not packages, and I'm not sure if it will work. You can try compiling it of course. I'm not entirely sure about which flags you'll need for cross-compiling. A good start is `./configure --fetch all --static all`. You will also need to set some environment variables (e.g. CXXFLAGS) to ensure building for the right architecture.

Comment: @DanielMewes Thanks for the response, I've decided to not try and compile it though. I decided I can run the RethinkDB-server on another computer and just connect to it, instead of running an instance of it on the Galileo-board =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not an answer per-se, but how I decided to do!**

I decided to not have the RethinkDB-server on the Galileo-board but instead just run the server on some other server and just connect to it. It would be interesting to see the performance but I just didn't have the time to try and make it work.

Sorry that this isn't a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

amd64 Ubuntu only needs a few packages installed to build i386 binaries.  I think installing `gcc-multilib` gets you most of what you need.  You might also need some `pkgname:i386` libraries installed.

You don't really need what's normally called a "cross-compile" setup, because the standard `/usr/bin/gcc` can make i586 binaries with the right options.  The default for `-m32` is i686: i.e. it uses the `cmov` instruction, which was added in P6 (PPro).

Configure your build to pass `-m32 -march=i586` as compiler options.  `-m32` probably also has to be a linker option, and some build commands might fail if they use other commands that need different options to specify operation on 32bit ELF binaries.

assuming your package uses a standard autoconf setup,

```
i586='-m32 -march=i586'
CFLAGS=$i586 LDFLAGS=$i586 CXXFLAGS=$i586 ./configure
make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)
```

Like people commented, you might want to build static libs.